# Same type of column but output different nulls in kdb

Tags: kdb

I used lj to join two tables and when I tried to compare if there is any difference I noticed that there are two different outputs for the nulls in same type.

```
meta tab
`cumQty "i" `   `
`cumQty "i" `   `


tab:

"x0"    0j  0Nj
"x2"    0j  0Nj
"x4"    0j  0Nj
"x6"    0j  0Nj
```

Do you know why this happened? I tried to cast the last column to int but still the same thing: last column always comes with N.

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Hi Terry. Can you provide an example?

Comment: the data i simulate may be different from the real data. but this is how i join a:(0!select  sum cumQty by id from parent where date=2017.06.26) lj (select child:sum cumQty) by id:odPOrID from child where date=2017.06.26), and then i run select from a where not cumQty = child

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a sample table of data?

`0j` in your example above looks like a zero value of type long `j`, not a null long value i.e. `0Nj`

Casting on the last column to any other type will change the column to the null type of that column, i.e. you are casting from null longs to null ints

```
q)0N 0N 0N 0Nj
0N 0N 0N 0N
q)`int$0N 0N 0N 0Nj
0N 0N 0N 0Ni
```

'N' denotes nulls and the small character `i` or `j` at the end of the list denotes the list datatype (`int` and `long` respectively); see here for more [code.kx DataTypes](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/datatypes/)

Answer (score 0):

when you do sum over a list of nulls you will get 0.

```
q)sum 0N 0N 0N 0Nj
0
```

when you do a lj, for ids not in the right hand table it will return a null

Is this you're issue?

Need more information to further explain what you're seeing.